# Cannot get node app to start on Heroku after deploy. Error: Cannot find module 'connect-livereload'

Tags: node.js, heroku, livereload

I am trying to deploy a new app to Heroku.  The app fails with the heroku log from below.  I am not including the node_modules in the git repo.  The NODE_ENV is set to production.  I am not sure where the problem is.

The app does run locally with no issues.

```
2014-02-17T05:35:24.435595+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-02-17T05:35:26.474183+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2014-02-17T05:35:27.719861+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-02-17T05:35:27.719861+00:00 app[web.1]: > vitalwall@0.0.0 start /app
2014-02-17T05:35:27.719861+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2014-02-17T05:35:27.719861+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-02-17T05:35:28.265208+00:00 app[web.1]: undefined
2014-02-17T05:35:28.503750+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-02-17T05:35:28.504352+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2014-02-17T05:35:28.504573+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2014-02-17T05:35:28.503929+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
2014-02-17T05:35:28.504764+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'connect-livereload'
2014-02-17T05:35:28.504764+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
2014-02-17T05:35:28.504764+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2014-02-17T05:35:28.504764+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2014-02-17T05:35:28.519755+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-02-17T05:35:28.526266+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 8
2014-02-17T05:35:28.504951+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2014-02-17T05:35:28.504764+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
2014-02-17T05:35:28.504764+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function._load (/app/node_modules/newrelic/lib/shimmer.js:209:38)
2014-02-17T05:35:28.526529+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2014-02-17T05:35:28.526825+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the vitalwall@0.0.0 start script.
2014-02-17T05:35:28.504764+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:39:32)
2014-02-17T05:35:28.504764+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.app.configure (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:391:61)
2014-02-17T05:35:28.504764+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.<anonymous> (/app/lib/config/express.js:14:13)
2014-02-17T05:35:28.504764+00:00 app[web.1]:     at module.exports (/app/lib/config/express.js:13:7)
2014-02-17T05:35:28.527785+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2014-02-17T05:35:28.527550+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the vitalwall package,
2014-02-17T05:35:28.528708+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via:
2014-02-17T05:35:28.528465+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server.js
2014-02-17T05:35:28.529935+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! command "/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
2014-02-17T05:35:28.530279+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! cwd /app
2014-02-17T05:35:28.525948+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! vitalwall@0.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2014-02-17T05:35:28.530785+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.24
2014-02-17T05:35:28.530567+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
2014-02-17T05:35:28.528194+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2014-02-17T05:35:28.533127+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2014-02-17T05:35:28.533624+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not ok code 0
2014-02-17T05:35:28.529186+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2014-02-17T05:35:28.528943+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls vitalwall
2014-02-17T05:35:28.529477+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
2014-02-17T05:35:28.531170+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2014-02-17T05:35:28.532660+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2014-02-17T05:35:28.532890+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
2014-02-17T05:35:29.769188+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-02-17T05:35:35.549258+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=young-everglades-2249.herokuapp.com request_id=aa5ff60b-1bf1-4de0-b547-    31175eebf1de fwd="50.143.67.190" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: What does your package.json look like?

Comment: I moved past this, so I no longer have the issue or file.  I went back and made a bunch of changes, but I believe the NODE_ENV was not correctly set.I used a Yeoman generator to create the Dist for Heroku.  I found issues in their repo stating that it did not set the NODE_ENV correctly.  Will be doing it by hand from now on.  Thanks!